# hive query execution using spark engine

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have setup HADOOP 2.7.2,HIVE 2.1,SCALA 2.11.8 and SPARK 2.0 in ubuntu 16.04 system.

Hadoop, hive and spark are working well. I could connect to hive cli and work with map-reduce without any problem.

I have to improve my hive query performance for order by clause.

I have to use Hive cli only, and could not use spark-shell.

I am trying to  use spark as query execution engine on hive

I am following  instructions as per this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started), I am setting some properties in hive as:

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set spark.home=/usr/local/spark
set spark.master=spark://ip:7077
```

I executed the query as

```
select count(*) from table_name;
```

then it throws this exception:

> failed to create spark client.

I increased the timeout of hive client connection to spark also. But, it is not useful.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Given this is the top Google hit for "local spark" "hive query", why are there so many down votes for the question and only answer without any explanations?

Answer (score -3):

First, I recommend you to use the shell and follow next steps:

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m
```

And you can run:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.sql("create table myTable (myField STRING) stored as orc")
```

If this works you can do another query SQL with hiveContext

Comment: we are using hbase storage handler tables in hive.

Comment: where do you mention 'hbase' ?  then you dont down my response

Comment: i updated by my question ... pls check ... hbase is out of context ... @youe --- sorry i did not down your response ... in fact thanks for reply ...